# ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am running an LDAP I can connect to, but in wanting to move away from slapd.conf and use ldif's, I am encountering the following problem(s).

When I type:`ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -s base -b "" -LLL "+"`

I get

```
dn:
structuralObjectClass: OpenLDAProotDSE
configContext: cn=config
namingContexts: dc=mysite,dc=com
supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.1
supportedControl: 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.18
supportedControl: 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2
supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.10.1
supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.1.22
supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319
supportedControl: 1.2.826.0.1.3344810.2.3
supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.1.13.2
supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.1.13.1
supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.1.12
supportedExtension: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.1
supportedExtension: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.3
supportedExtension: 1.3.6.1.1.8
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.1.14
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.1
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.2
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.3
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.4
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.5
supportedLDAPVersion: 3
supportedSASLMechanisms: SRP
supportedSASLMechanisms: SCRAM-SHA-1
supportedSASLMechanisms: GS2-IAKERB
supportedSASLMechanisms: GS2-KRB5
supportedSASLMechanisms: GSSAPI
supportedSASLMechanisms: GSS-SPNEGO
supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: OTP
supportedSASLMechanisms: CRAM-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: NTLM
entryDN:
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema
```

I then try: `sudo ldapsearch -H ldapi:// -Y EXTERNAL -b "cn=config" -LLL -Q`

Resulting in:
`ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`

When I try using ldap:// instead of ldapi://, I get:

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Unknown authentication method (-6)
    additional info: SASL(-4): no mechanism available:
```

I can find a lot of stuff about TLS and authentication, but I have not configured any TLS/SSL so not sure why this would happen.  Anyone experience this?

Comment: What happens if you run `ldapsearch` with `ldapi:///` (note the THREE slashes), e.g. `sudo ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -b "cn=config" -LLL -Q`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your *slapd* is listening on LDAPI socket at all?

It has to get started with `slapd -h "ldapi:// ldap://" to e.g. listen on Unix domain socket (default path name depends on build options) and clear-text LDAP (389/tcp).

Depending on your Linux distribution (which one?) there is probably some config file for setting parameters for the start script.

Also note that you would some more config to directly map Linux user *root* to a LDAP user granted write access to *cn=config* for more reconfiguration.

In entry *cn=config* (frontend configuration) you need to rewrite authc-DN to proper authz-DN:

```
olcAuthzRegexp: {0}"gidnumber=0\+uidnumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" "cn=config"
```

In entry *olcDatabase={0}config* you would need an ACL like this:

```
olcAccess: {0}to
  dn.subtree="cn=config"
  by dn.base="cn=config" write
```

Comment: This does indeed resolve this particular issue.  I couldn't find this in documentation, thank you.  Now I just get the error "No such object (32)", so i will work on that!  Thanks.

Comment: I've added some more information.

Answer (score 1):

root@ldap:~#ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f mod_ssl.ldif
Resulting in: ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

root@ldap:~#sudo service slapd start

Job for slapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status slapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Issue:- Failed to start slapd
slapd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
"tls init def ctx failed: -1"

Check your SSL certificate .crt/.key should be fine

root@ldap:~#ls -lsrt /etc/ldap/sasl2/
root@ldap:~#grep -R /etc/ldap/slapd.d

root@ldap:~#cat /etc/ldap/slapd.d/'cn=config.ldif'

olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ldap/sasl2/maneet.crt
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ldap/sasl2/maneet.key

#sudo service slapd start

Issue resolved